# teradata Z between X and Y vs Z >= Y and Z < X

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to use equality signs instead of the between operator inside of a case statement, however I am getting a syntax error

```
case 
when item_price between 5 and 6 then '5-6'
when item_price between 6 and 7 then '6-7
end as price_group
```

However I am aware this will create some kind of overlap between item prices that are exactly 6, so I would prefer to use

```
case 
when item_price >= 5 and item_price < 6 then '5-6'
when item_price >= 6 and item_price < 7 then '6-7
end as price_group
```

The second query gives me error :

```
SELECT Failed 3706: Syntax error: expected something between '<' and '='.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to check a range every time, only the range higher boundary

```
case 
when item_price <= 5 then '...-5'
when item_price <= 6 then '5-6'
when item_price <= 7 then '6-7'
else                      '7-...'
end as price_group
```